# Control-m runtime variables: sh vs powershell

Tags: bash, powershell, sh, control-m

I've faced a problem with runtime variables in control-m.
**I have to migrate some powershell scripts to linux shell, and it doesn't work same way during the execution.**

In general, powershell script looks like this:

```
    write-HOST "SOME_VARIABLE_NO2=OTHER_VAL2"
    write-HOST "SOME_VARIABLE_NO3=OTHER_VAL3"
    write-HOST "SOME_VARIABLE_NO4=OTHER_VAL4"
```

Linux script is

```
    #!/bin/sh

    echo "SOME_VARIABLE_NO2=OTHER_VAL2"
    echo "SOME_VARIABLE_NO3=OTHER_VAL3"
    echo "SOME_VARIABLE_NO4=OTHER_VAL4"
```

**Now, during execution I have the following outputs**

1. For Powershell:

```
>SOME_VARIABLE_NO2=OTHER_VAL2
>[Extracted runtime parameter: 'RT_SOME_VARIABLE_NO2' ==> 'OTHER_VAL2'] 
>
>SOME_VARIABLE_NO3=OTHER_VAL3
>[Extracted runtime parameter: 'RT_SOME_VARIABLE_NO3' ==> 'OTHER_VAL3'] 
>
>SOME_VARIABLE_NO4=OTHER_VAL4
>[Extracted runtime parameter: 'RT_SOME_VARIABLE_NO4' ==> 'OTHER_VAL4']
```

2. For Linux

```
>SOME_VARIABLE_NO2=OTHER_VAL2
>SOME_VARIABLE_NO3=OTHER_VAL3
>SOME_VARIABLE_NO4=OTHER_VAL4
>
>[Extracted runtime parameter: 'RT_SOME_VARIABLE_NO3' ==> 'OTHER_VAL3'] 
>[Extracted runtime parameter: 'RT_SOME_VARIABLE_NO2' ==> 'OTHER_VAL2'] 
>[Extracted runtime parameter: 'RT_SOME_VARIABLE_NO4' ==> 'OTHER_VAL4']
```

**How can I make bash and control-m to perform same way as ps1&control-m? Is this matter of control-m configuration?**

In powershell write-host command could assign a variable value just after executing this line. In bash the whole script has to execute before the variable value is beign assigned. I'm looking for solution that allows control-m to assign variable in bash as it works in powershell - after executing particular line

I need those variables during the execution, because they store e.g PID of process, so that I can kill it (for whatever reason)

I must admit, that I have no idea how control-m works. I can ask question to person who has access, but at this point I don't even know what to ask..

Answer (score 0):

Best practice, in this case, is to use the Control-M Job Definition to store your variables.

In the Job Def, halfway down the first tab, is the Variables field. Here you can use the %%PARMn special Control-M Variable as below -

**Type ....... Name ................................. Value**  
Local ...... SOME_VARIABLE_NO1 .... OTHER_VAL1 
Local ...... SOME_VARIABLE_NO2 .... OTHER_VAL2  
Local ...... SOME_VARIABLE_NO3 .... OTHER_VAL3 
Local ...... PARM1 ............................... SOME_VARIABLE_NO1 
Local ...... PARM2 ............................... SOME_VARIABLE_NO2  
Local ...... PARM3 ............................... SOME_VARIABLE_NO3

Local means the scope of the variable is limited to this one job/script (you can use different scopes, all the way up to Global).

The values %%PARM1, %%PARM2, etc will be reflected by $1, $2 and so on.

BMC have this video guide on their channel -

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nPKbOh8tUNU

there is a good guide here too -

https://communities.bmc.com/message/832637#832637

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your response! Unfortunatelly, my problem is slightly different -I want to assign a Control-m variable based on value from script - in my particural case I want to assign script PID into variable so that I can kill the process if I need to.

Comment: In powershell write-host command could assign a variable value just after executing this line. In bash the whole script has to execute before the variable value is beign assigned. I'm looking for solution that allows control-m to assign variable in bash as it works in powershell - after executing particular line

Comment: In that case you can just use the ctmvar utility to set a Control-M variable -        
   ctmvar -action SET -var "var" -varexpr "var_value"